# In pagy gem in rails, how do you hide pagination when unneeded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

The pagination works well when it's needed. But even when it's not needed -- for example, when # set for pagination is 100 and the list is less than 100 --, the pagination shows like this:

‹ Prev
1
Next ›

How can I eliminate this?

My controller:

```rb
    @pagy, @users = pagy(User.all, items:100, link_extra: 'class="" style="color:#222222; margin-left:3px;"')
```

My view:

```
    <%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>
```

Otherwise followed the [documentation](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/how-to#quick-start)

Answer (score 12):

The solution was to add this line:

```
<%== pagy_nav(@pagy) if @pagy.pages > 1 %>
```

Because unlike will_paginate or other pagination gems, pagy does not hide the link automatically.